# Not able to send and receive data in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, knex.js

I'm making an electron app and I'm not able to send or receive data. I want to send data that has originated in my `main.js` to my `mainWindow.html`. I'm using knex with sqlite 3. I have tried several approaches. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

---

### Relevant Code

---

**main.js**

```
app.on("ready", function () {
    [...]

    taskContents = [];

    knex
    .select("task")
    .from("task")
    .then((task) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
            // console.log(task[i].task);
            taskContents.push(task[i].task);
        }

            // I want to send task contents ===================
        ipcMain.on("item:task", function(e, taskContents){
        mainWindow.webContents.send("item:task", taskContents);
    
    }
        

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    [...]    

});
```

**mainWindow.html**

```
  ipcRenderer.on("item:tasks", function(e, item){
    console.log(item);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In **main.js** you have this code:

```
ipcMain.on("item:task", function(e, taskContents){
    mainWindow.webContents.send("item:task", taskContents);
}
```

Which means it'll wait for an `item:task` message in the main process before an `item:task` message is sent to `mainWindow`.

I'd suggest removing the `ipcMain.on` like this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.send("item:task", 'messageData');
```

But also in your **mainWindow.html** you're using `item:tasks` instead of `item:task`:

E.g. Should be:

```
ipcRenderer.on("item:task", function(e, item){
```

Instead of:

```
ipcRenderer.on("item:tasks", function(e, item){
```

Comment: Still nothing appears in my console.